# Notifications in iOS with sound only, no badges?

Tags: swiftui, uilocalnotification

Is it possible to send sound notifications only, without badges (locally)? I have tried setting only the sound property of UNMutableNotificationContent(), but the notification won't sound or show up without also setting at least the title-property.

You can however manually go into settings and disable the badges on the lock screen, notification center and so on. That would be ok for my app too if you could do this programmatically. Anyone know if it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to request with `UNAuthorizationOptions`? If not, do this:

```swift
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.sound]) { (granted, error) in
    //TODO
}
```

**Updated**: FYI, I think you consider `background update notification`, and it is handled from Backend side. The `aps` field on remote notification payload can contain the `content-available` property. Setting this property with 1 will make remote notification silent. It means there are no badge, sound, alert, etc.

[Configuring a Background Update Notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html)

Comment: I have tried with .sound only. And I get both sound and banners.

Comment: @irrbloss I updated the answer, maybe it's what you were looking for.

Comment: I had to include .alert in the requestAuthorization-options. Then manually disable banners in the notification settings for the app. I wish there was some api-call to set this, instead of instructing the users how to set up everything manually.